# python pygame program not working properly when switching to linux

Tags: python, linux, pygame

I had a program that receives a key from the user in pygame environment and then it prints some information on the console and do some other work
It worked fine for me on windows
when switching to linux with the very same code it doesn't work properly  ,and it seems like not responding to any input keys from keyboard 
and I tried to put 1/0 to test where's the exact problem like Mr Hyperboreus suggested (comments in code below )
and I found the exact problem in "if event.key "

the function which I use :

```
for event in pygame.event.get(KEYDOWN):
    # 1/0 --> it give me an error when pressing any button
    if event.key == K_i:
        numbers.insert(0,number)
        #1/0 --> is not giving me any error when pressing i
        print "ingoing"

        return 1         #"ingoing"




    elif event.key==K_m:
        numbers.insert(0,number)
        print "missed"

        return 2             #"missed"

    elif event.key==K_o:
        numbers.insert(0,number)
        print "outgoing"

        return 3             #"outgoing"

    elif event.key==K_l:
        disp_log() #this function displays test on the pygame screen 
else : 
    None
```

and I play the script from the terminal by this command
    python xxxxx.py

I am installing python2.7 , python3 and python3.2 and pygame 
and I tried removing them and installing them again and the same problem exists

Comment: Please put a `1 / 0` on a line before `print "ingoing"`, just to make sure this condition is ever met. If your script throws an error when pressing `i`, there is something wrong with the output. If it does not throw an error, you never reach the `print` line. Please post result.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: It didn't give an error!! , smart suggestion

Comment: Smart suggestion: (a) your event loop isn't running, (b) you never get key events, (c) solar flares. Really, I am just poking with a stick in a muddy pond. Check your whole script and see how far your code actually gets executed, if the main event loop runs, etc.

Comment: @Hyperboreus : No everything else is okay , as I told u I tested it on windows and It's working
when I put 1/0 immediately after "for event" statement it gave me an error when I pushed any button
but when I put it inside any if condition it doesn't give me an error which means the problem is in "event.key" !

Comment: Put a `print event.key` as first line into the `for`. And use the printed values for your conditions.

Comment: It worked very fine for me , Thanks , It's really ur experience
@Hyperboreus

Comment: why not you put your answer in an "answer" so anybody else can see it 
Regards,

Comment: If you have found a working solution, answer it yourself and accept your own answer. That is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Hyperboreus suggested , I put a print event.key as first line into the for. And I use the printed values for the if  conditions instead of "K_i" or "K_m"..etc

**and it worked very fine for me .**

and probably pygame in the my version which is the newest removed the option of using K_key and replaced it with something else. but the upward method worked fine for me , Thanks to @Hyperboreus